# how to skip multiple rows for one id

Tags: php, sql

Hi guys i use this query to find online friends (users have a session_time >30 sec ) but sometime some users have multiple sessions rows then in friend list one username repeated multiple times
i need to know how i can skip multiple sessions rows for one user ?!thank you.

```
$friends_id = "95";

$time = time() - 50;     
$query_b = "SELECT session_user_id FROM phpbb_sessions WHERE session_time > '" . $time . "' AND session_user_id = '".$friends_id."'";
$result_b = mysql_query($query_b,$connect2->connect());
$row_b = mysql_fetch_array($result_b)
$connect2->disconnect();
```

Comment: Actually, you select same parameter, as you have in WHERE condition, so output always will be same ID(or emty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DISTINCT keyword:

```
SELECT DISTINCT session_user_id FROM phpbb_sessions WHERE
```

Comment: Thank you i think its work but however i need time to check in my forum i will send back my result.